# Init Methods: Whats the difference between these two?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, init

i am currently reading the "Programming with Objective C" manual from Apple and it shows these two init methods. what is the difference between them and when would each one be appropriate to use?

```
  - (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName dateOfBirth: (NSDate *)aDateOfBirth {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _firstName = aFirstName;
        _lastName = aLastName;
        _dateOfBirth = aDateOfBirth;
    }

    return self;

}
```

vs

```
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName {
    return [self initWithFirstName:aFirstName lastName:aLastName dateOfBirth:nil];
}
```

manual can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW15

Comment: The first one is the proper one, try it. What does happen if you try the second?

Comment: The second one calls itself and so would loop infinitely. Is this the question you intended to ask or did you perhaps mistype one of the methods?

Comment: In the manual referenced, the method being called has a third `dateOfBirth` parameter.

Comment: Your post seems to be based on a copy-paste error on your part. Could you please correct the snippet and elaborate if there is some other point of confusion?

Comment: got it.. fixed the error. so now whats the difference between the 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is circular and will lead to infinite recursion.

**edit:**

With the updated question, the second version of the initializer is just a convenience because you no longer need to specify the third parameter.

Comment: Perhaps you may explain to the OP the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: Interesting.. why would Apple advise doing this in their own manual?

Comment: @user1779598 Apple wouldn't.... you must have mistyped one of the methods. If a class has multiple init methods, they usually call up to a single "designated" initializer, which is likely what the manual you are referring to is suggesting... but you likely didn't copy it perfectly :)

Comment: @isaac uhh well they did. follow the link above to see for yourself. i copied and pasted their code

Comment: @user1779598: No, the equivalent snippet in Apple's code calls `[self initWithFirstName:aFirstName lastName:aLastName dateOfBirth:nil];`. Notice the `dateOfBirth:nil` bit that you omitted. Different method.

Comment: I can see how the Apple documentation can potentially confusing. It first introduces the `initWithFirstName:lastName:` method, then later introduces the `initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:dateOfBirth:` method, but it doesn't show the implementation.

Comment: yes @ThomasW, i'm completely confused and wondering which order im suppose to implement each one

Comment: @user1779598 Now that you've updated your question, is there still a problem or has the answer become clear?

Comment: need more clarification @ThomasW. so with the first example i create my own instance variables or is this with using @property? also when and where do i set the aFirstName, aLastName, aDOB variables that i pass to the init method

Comment: It doesn't make a big difference if you use an instance variable or property. (I'd recommend property.) Check out my edits to your question where I added an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is normal custom initialization, it sets your parameters correctly and initializes your class.

The second one calls itself, so it will call itself again and again and again in an infinite recursion ultimately leading to a stackoverflow -- the app will freeze essentially and crash.

The apple docs does not suggest that.... you might have misread it

---

The apple docs still does not suggest it, but it comes close:

```
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName {
return [self initWithFirstName:aFirstName lastName:aLastName dateOfBirth:nil]; // Not the same method, passes dateOfBirth parameter.
}
```

What the method that gets called **may** look like:

```
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName dateOfBirth: (NSDate *)dateOfBirth {

   if (self = [super init]) {

         _firstName = aFirstName;
         _lastName = aLastName
         _dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
   }

        return self;

}
```

It calls another method which is similar, but passes a `dateOfBirth` parameter, its not the same method.

---

Ok, so the difference is simple, if the class that calls either method does not want to pass a `dateOfBirth` parameter from within the class, and this Person instance does not have a `dateOfBirth` he wishes to specify, the writer of code might find it a bit hacky to write `nil` willy nilly. So it is a convenience method, you don't pass a `dateOfBirth`, just the first and last name, and it calls the other method with simply `nil` for `dateOfBirth`. Its just a way for the writer of code to not feel scared when he writes `nil`.

So everything gets initialized in both methods.

Comment: Perhaps.. but kindly refer to the link above and see for yourself. i am not making this up... its all under the section "Access Instance Variables Directly from Initializer Methods"

Comment: Fair enough.. so whats the difference between the 2 methods now?

Answer (score 0):

As @ThomasW points out the second case is wrong. In the first case, you call `[super init]` to let the *base* class yours is derived from initialize *their* share of the object you are instantiating.

That works because because `super` indicates that the `init` message should be received by the base class which knows what to do. Note that it does not know how to remember your first name or last name.

However, in the second case, the `init` message is sent to `self`, and that is the `init` you are calling from. This means that `init` will keep invoking itself until you crash.

It looks like you assume `aFirstName` and `aLastName` are in some magical way assigned, but you have to teach your objects how to do this and implement it yourself exactly in this `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is written in the manual:

```
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName {
    return [self initWithFirstName:aFirstName lastName:aLastName dateOfBirth:nil];
}
```

So it doesn't cause an infinite loop because the called method is another, it's not recursive.

**EDIT**

The second method is to use when you don't want to initialise your object with the dateOfBirth. Indeed if you use initWithFirstName:lastName: , this property will be nil.

Comment: Comments/answers suggesting infinite recursion were based on the originally posted question, which was mistyped. What is shown in the manual and what is *now* visible in the edited question is correct and doesn't loop.